# Trigger Lookup field

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I have a List as seen below ,

```
List<asset> Asset101 = [select Id,OwnerId,quantity,Name,Refresh_Asset_To__c,
                            Refresh_Asset_To__r.Id,AccountId 
                         from asset ] ;
```

The field Refresh_Asset_To__c is a lookup to the product object, I want to insert a new opportunity with Refresh_Asset_To__c being the opportunity product.

How do I go about retrieving the Id for Refresh_Asset_To__c and looking up the  PriceBookEntry  Id.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Opportunity for each Asset in your List?

Comment: Also, are you going to filter your List of Assets? Right now your List contains every Asset in your org.

Comment: `REfresh_Asset_to__c` and `Refresh_Asset_to__r.Id` are exactly the same; you only need one (the former)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Refresh_Asset_To__c` is a reference to the Product2 object, you will need to iterate the list of assets and retrieve the Product2 Ids, then query on the Pricebook table:

```
Set<Id> pb_ids = new Set<Id>();
for (Asset a : the_asset_list) {
    pb_ids.add(a.Refresh_Asset_To__c);
}
List<PricebookEntry> pricebook_entries = [SELECT
    Id,
    Product2Id
    FROM PricebookEntry
    WHERE Product2Id IN :product_ids
];
// do what you want with your pricebook entries after this...
//
// Since the PricebookEntry object also references the Product2 you can
// sort these two lists by the product id, so it is easier to match the
// PricebookEntryId.
```